# Delete records returned for .ToList

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have a BLOG Table with COMMENTS Table with RESPONSES Table.
Example:

- BLOG ONE

  1. COMMENTS=A

     - Response 1
     - Response 2
  2. COMMENT-B

     - Response 1
     - Response 2
     - Response 3
- BLOG TWO

  1. COMMENTS-A

     - Response 1
     - Response 2
     - Response 3
  2. COMMENT-B

     - Response 1
     - Response 2

If we DELETE 'BLOG TWO' I need to **delete all RESPONSE and all COMMENTS and the BLOG post** as well.

I think the solution is to Delete all records returned from a .ToList(). This is what I am thinking/tried. I can seem to do a 'IN' list type of command.

```
ctx.BlogResponse.Where(b => b.blogCommentID = xxMyListItemxxx** ).ForEach(ctx.BlogResponse.DeleteObject);
```

How do I delete records from/contained within a .ToList()?

Comment: I would recommend to add cascading referential integrity constraints to your db schema. Then dependent data will get deleted automatically. See msdn for details if you use sqlserver: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found '.DeleteObject' that deleted items contained within a returned LIST. I was able to do a few calls and it worked fairly well.

> ctx.BlogComments.Where(c => c.blogID ==
>   id).ToList().ForEach(ctx.BlodComments.DeleteObject);
>
> ctx.BlogResponse.Where(c => c.bCommID ==
>   cID).ToList().ForEach(ctx.BlogResponse.DeleteObject);

The .ForEach is something I haven't used before and in this case, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework isn't very good at bulk operations like this. There are ways to accomplish what you're asking, but they are clunky and slow.

The best solution is to just put an `ON DELETE CASCADE` on your foreign key constraint linking the Comments to a Blog, and the one linking your Responses to a Comment. That way, you simply delete the blog in EF, and the database will very quickly and automatically delete all of the related data.